# Get all entities in azure table without partition key

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a azure table with specific partition keys and unique row keys.

Is there a way that I can fetch all the records from my table irrespective of the partition key ?

Comment: if you have less or just single partition you can use rowkeys to query.

Comment: Yea.. that worked .. i used the rowkeys to query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can retrieve any individual row/entity from the table, however... this will result in a full table scan if the partition key isn't use which is not an ideal use case, especially for large tables.

What language are you using and I'll see if I can't come up with a sample?

Comment: He mentionned C# in the question

Answer (score 0):

Though not recommended, I had to go with a full table scan.

And I used the row key without specifying the partition key, which brought down all the records.